# percentage height of absolutely positioned blocks

Tags: css

This is a question motivated by curiosity rather than an actual problem. I'm trying to understand css better.

Percentage height (and width) is supposed to be relative to the containing block ([see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-height)).

The containing block of an absolutely positioned block is the nearest ancestor that is "positioned" (ie. absolute, relative or fixed - [see here](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)).

So I would expect the inner div in this example to span the whole available height:

```
<div class="full-height">

  <div>
    <div id="main-block">
    x
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

html, body, .full-height {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

with this css:

```
#main-block {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Or just take [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v4xf41ct/1/).

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not absolutely positioned your main-block. Do that and it will take the full height.

```css
html, body, .full-height {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#main-block {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute
}
```

```html
    <div class="full-height">

      <div>
        <div id="main-block">
        x
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: missing a semicolon(;) after the absolute position. :-)

Comment: @FlorianDoyen - Nope. The semicolon is a declaration separator in CSS. You don't need one between the last declaration and the end of the declaration block. See "ruleset" in the [Grammar](https://drafts.csswg.org/css2/#grammar).

Comment: @Grammar, it's a really bad practice to forgot a semicolon. I know what it does and I know you don't NEED to have it on last instruction. BUT : Don't put it add more reason to your CSS properties to do not works because if you add a property below, it will not be executed because you didn't put a semicolon... So... My personal advice here would be to NEVER forgot a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is simply that you had an additional `<div>` that is the parent of `#main-block`, which doesn't have a set height. Considering you don't specify a height of `100%` for **this** element, it only utilises the **default** height. For a `<div>`, that's `0px`.

`#main-block` attempts to takes up `100%` of the height of this extra `<div>` (and not its parents). Considering `#main-block` has content (the `x`), it will automatically expand to allow the content to be displayed.

Removing this extra `<div>` showcases a full page with a red background, as expected:

```css
html, body, .full-height {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#main-block {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-height">
  <div id="main-block">
    x
  </div>
</div>
```

Conversely, keeping this extra parent `<div>` in and giving it a height of `100%` will **also** give you a full-height red background. Note that this only gives you as much width as the `#main-block` content itself though; if you want it to be full width, you'll need to specify the `width` in addition to the `height`:

```css
html, body, .full-height {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#main-block {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.full-height > div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-height">
  <div>
    <div id="main-block">
      x
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And also note that the **default** position for a `<div>` is `static`, not `absolute`.

Hope this helps! :)